# How to ignore consecutive duplicates on insert statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I want to ignore duplicates (or update key on duplicates), but only on consecutive duplicates.

Say my initial table looks like this (`uk` and `a` are column names):

```
uk a
----
x  1
```

Iteration 1 inserts 1 so I want this to be ignored in order to avoid duplicates.

Iteration 2 inserts 2 and my table now looks like this:

```
uk  a
----
x   1
x   2
```

Iteration 3 inserts 1 and because the last row where my unique key = x was different to 1 then I want 1 to be inserted again:

```
uk  a
----
x   1
x   2
x   1
```

How can this be achieved in MySQL?

My current solution is to query in data from the table first and remove these duplicates, but I would prefer that it was handled by MySQL.

Comment: `uk` is not a unique key since you have three rows with the same value in `uk` which is not possible for the key

Comment: Have you tried creating a function/procedure to store the values? In there you can first select the last inserted row, and if it suits you, insert the new or discard it.

Comment: I have never come across an inbuilt mysql function which would do this, and  I strongly suspect that there isn't one given your peculiar requirement,

Comment: As mentioned `uk` is not a unique key. Maybe you are trying to say that you want this behavior per `uk`? So I can insert y|3 now and a following x|1 would still fail, for the last inserted value for x was 1?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, unique key is the wrong word. If I didn't want duplicates then I could use unique key on uk + a, but I want to allow duplicates as long as they are not consecutive. The reason I use unique key is how I originally modelled it before I realised that I actually want duplicates.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, I believe that is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

You need a column that will be an auto-increment primary key

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 uk CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 a INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO your_table(uk, a) VALUES ('x', 1)
```

now you can use the following insert command to avoid duplicates as you describe it

```
INSERT INTO your_table(uk, a)
SELECT 'x', 1 FROM your_table t1
JOIN (
   SELECT max(id) maxid, uk 
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY uk
) t ON t.maxid = t1.id and 
       t1.a != 1 and
       t.uk = 'x'
```

The second insert can be the following

```
INSERT INTO your_table(uk, a)
SELECT 'x', 2 FROM your_table t1
JOIN (
   SELECT max(id) maxid, uk 
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY uk
) t ON t.maxid = t1.id and 
       t1.a != 2 and
       t.uk = 'x'
```

The third insert will be the same as the first one and the result table will be as expected.

See the [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a82b59ba5d93c8f73eda6da15648d216)

Answer (score 0):

From your table it is not visible, which values got inserted last. Data in a table is considered unordered. So for your last example we know there are the three records x|1, x|1, x|2 in the table, but not whether x|1 or x|2 was inserted last. You'd need an additional column to indicate this. This could be a datetime or an ascending ID.

If you don't want to change your table, you need a helper table containing the last record instead. Anyway, you'd write a before-insert trigger to look up the last inserted value and throw an error when the new record matches the last inserted record for th `uk`.

```
create table mytable(uk char(1), a int);
create table mytable_helper(uk char(1), a int, primary key (uk));

create trigger mytable_ins BEFORE INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
begin
  DECLARE msg VARCHAR(128);
  if exists (select * from mytable_helper h where new.uk = h.uk and new.a = h.a) then 
    set msg = concat('Consecutive duplicate for a = ', new.a, ' and uk = ''', new.uk, '''.');
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
  else
    replace into mytable_helper (uk, a) values (new.uk, new.a);
  end if;
end;

insert into mytable (uk, a) values ('x', 1);
insert into mytable (uk, a) values ('x', 2);
insert into mytable (uk, a) values ('x', 1);
insert into mytable (uk, a) values ('y', 3);
insert into mytable (uk, a) values ('x', 1);

Error(s), warning(s):
Consecutive duplicate for a = 1 and uk = 'x'.
```

REXTESTER http://rextester.com/XOG65602